# How should the result of getDeviceDensity() method from Codename One be used?

Tags: codenameone, dpi

Depending on which skin I use in the simulator, the result from the following method differs :

```
Display.getInstance().getDeviceDensity();
```

The results have nothing to do with the real device density since for a Xoom skin it outputs 30 (149 ppi in reality), for a an Iphone 6 it outputs 50 (329 in reality).

I noticed that because I need to translate char height measured in Gimp (72 dpi) into the device world so that it looks alike on an image.

Any help on that topic would be appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaDocs for [getDeviceDensity](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Display.html#getDeviceDensity--) state:

> Returns one of the density variables appropriate for this device,
>   notice that density doesn't always correspond to resolution and an
>   implementation might decide to change the density based on DPI
>   constraints.
>
> Returns:
>       one of the DENSITY constants of Display

The DENSITY constants refers to [one of these](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Display.html#DENSITY_HD).

Notice you can also use [convertToPixels](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Display.html#convertToPixels-float-) which is probably a far better API to use. The density API is mostly used to pick the right multi image and should rarely be used in user code.

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks @Shai! I will give convertToPixels method a try!